# How to bind to OnItemSelectionChanged of a list view

Tags: c++, delegates, unreal-engine4

In Unreal Engine 4, I want to bind an event to `UListView::OnItemSelectionChanged`. That event `FOnItemSelectionChanged` requires a `NullableItemType`, so I'm passing a pointer to the list entry class of the list view (my custom class derived from `IUserObjectListEntry`) as parameter.

```
UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API UMyListViewEntry : public UUserWidget, public IUserObjectListEntry
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    // Members and functions don't matter here.
};

UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    void NativeConstruct() final
    {
        MyList->OnItemSelectionChanged.AddDynamic(this, &UMyUserWidget::MyEventCallback);
    }
    void MyEventCallback(UMyListViewEntry* e)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
private:
    UPROPERTY(meta = (BindWidget))
    UListView* MyList;
};
```

However, the `AddDynamic()` call causes the error

> C2228: Left of ".__Internal_AddDynamic" has to be in a class/structure/union

so I suppose, the signature of the callback function I want to bind (the `MyEventCallback()`) is wrong.

What would be the correct signature for a function which should be bound to `UListView::OnItemSelectionChanged`?

Comment: Presumably `OnItemSelectionChanged` is actually some sort of getter, could it be as simple as `MyList->OnItemSelectionChanged().AddDynamic(...`?

Comment: @George Yes, you are correct. I got three different approaches to work now (one of them using that event getter). I think I will add an answer once I have time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only about the signature of the callback, but also about how to add the callback.

#### Option #1: Use return value of OnItemSelectionChanged (the callback will be limited to UObject)

In `UListView`, its member `OnItemSelectionChanged` is implemented via a macro `IMPLEMENT_TYPED_UMG_LIST`, which does

```
virtual FOnItemSelectionChanged& OnItemSelectionChanged() const override { return OnItemSelectionChangedEvent; }
```

So to add a callback function to the delegate, use the return value:

```
UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    void NativeConstruct() final
    {
        auto event = MyList->OnItemSelectionChanged();
        event.AddUObject(this, &UMyUserWidget::MyEventCallback);
    }
    void MyEventCallback(UObject* e)
    {
        // implementation details, cast e to UMyListViewEntry*
    }
    // ...
};
```

You are limited to callbacks having `UObject*` as parameter (`UListView` is a specialization of its base classes using `UObject` as entry type).

The delegate which is available in blueprint (`BP_OnItemSelectionChanged`) can't be used, since it is private.

#### Option #2: Define custom delegate

If you want to use your custom entry type directly as parameter in the callback, you either could

1. implement your own list view or
2. derive from `UListView` and call a custom delegate in `virtual void OnSelectionChangedInternal(UObject* FirstSelectedItem)`

While the first approach is similar to the `UListView` implementation, the second approach is very short and might look similar to `BP_OnItemSelectionChanged`:

```
DECLARE_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_TwoParams(FOnMyListItemSelectionChanged, UMyListViewEntry*, bool);
UCLASS(meta = (EntryInterface = UserObjectListEntry, EntryClass = UMyListViewEntry))
class PROJECT_API UMyListView : public UListView
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    FOnMyListItemSelectionChanged OnMyListItemSelectionChanged;
private:
    void OnSelectionChangedInternal(UObject* FirstSelectedItem) override
    {
        Super::OnSelectionChangedInternal(FirstSelectedItem);
        auto entry = Cast<UMyListViewEntry>(FirstSelectedItem);
        OnMyListItemSelectionChanged.Broadcast(entry, entry != nullptr);
    }
};
UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    void NativeConstruct() final
    {
        MyList->OnMyListItemSelectionChanged.AddUObject(this, &UMyUserWidget::MyEventCallback);
    }
    void MyEventCallback(UMyListViewEntry* e, bool isSelected)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
private:
    UPROPERTY(meta = (BindWidget), meta = (EntryClass = UMyListViewEntry))
    UMyListView* MyList;
};
```